# Open a menu from buttons

Tags: java, jbutton

hello eveybody i created this code :

```
package project1;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.ImageProducer;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSeparator;

public class ccc {
public static void main(String[] args){
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Food delivery"); // Create a frame
frame.setSize(1600, 1400); // Set the frame size
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // New since JDK 1.4
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setVisible(true); // Display the frame

JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
JPanel panel1 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("hamburger.jpg");
frame.setIconImage(icon.getImage());
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

try {
frame.setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new        File("fd12.jpg")))));
} catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));

JLabel label = new JLabel("Welcome to Food Delivery");

label.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.BOLD, 38));
label.setForeground(Color.black);

System.out.println("");

JButton btn1= new JButton("Breakfast");
btn1.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.BOLD, 16));
btn1.setForeground(Color.BLACK);

JButton btn2= new JButton("Starters");
btn2.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.BOLD, 16));
btn2.setForeground(Color.BLACK);

JButton btn3= new JButton("Main Dishes");
btn3.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.BOLD, 16));
btn3.setForeground(Color.BLACK);

JButton btn4= new JButton("Deserts");
btn4.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.BOLD, 16));
btn4.setForeground(Color.BLACK);

JButton btn5= new JButton("Drinks");
btn5.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.BOLD, 16));
btn5.setForeground(Color.BLACK);

frame.add(label);
frame.add(new JSeparator());
frame.add(btn1);
frame.add(btn2);
frame.add(btn3);
frame.add(btn4);
frame.add(btn5);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);

}}
```

screen shot :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4PFc.jpg)

[image]

I would love to get a new page inside the page that get opens for each buttons and inside I will write the menu of the food to select and near to it have the prices written ?? please help me I couldn't not do it at all and can know how ...

Thanks

Comment: Sonds like [Card Layout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) is something to check up on?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JPanel to draw things inside other Containers. (JPanel and JFrame are Containers)

But u said u just want to write text. So u can use a JTextArea.
Javadoc will help u.

Comment: hello my friend i am a beginner i dont really now how to write it .. i want when i click in one of the menu to open a new page inside with next and previous and in that page to write everything i want with prices and select box

Comment: Having next & previous will be hard. But you can use JTabbedPane to open new pages. Javadoc now. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments by Emz, a `CardLayout` is the best fist for this scenario. Create a `JPanel` for each of the menus and add them to a `JPanel` with `CardLayout`. Then use the buttons to switch between the panels.

Here is an example:

```
public class Example extends JPanel {

    Example() {

        JPanel starters = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        starters.add(new JLabel("starters..."));
        JPanel drinks = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        drinks.add(new JLabel("drinks..."));

        JPanel main = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
        main.add(starters, "starters");
        main.add(drinks, "drinks");

        JPanel buttons = new JPanel();
        JButton startersButton = new JButton("Starters");
        startersButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                CardLayout cl = (CardLayout)(main.getLayout());
                cl.show(main, "starters");
            }
        });

        JButton drinksButton = new JButton("Starters");
        drinksButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                CardLayout cl = (CardLayout)(main.getLayout());
                cl.show(main, "drinks");
            }
        });

        buttons.add(startersButton);
        buttons.add(drinksButton);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(main);
        add(buttons, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    }
}
```

Add to a frame and run.

Comment: i tried to add the code to a frame but i have an error :

here is the code in the link : http://textuploader.com/5f4zf